# When creating private products in bugzilla do I need to have user groups instead of system groups?

Tags: mysql, sql, bugzilla

I am trying to create a product in bugzilla that would allow our client access to ONLY that product and not everything else.  I created a user group but it seems everyone in the office (whether part of that group or not) can see the new product.

I think the issue is that we are very small and never needed user groups before so all of us are in the various system groups.  Do I need to go through and first, create new groups based on the system groups and then utilize these new user groups on each of our current products?

The system groups do not have the "use for bugs" checkbox so I have not been able to even see the Edit Group table for any of them.

Thx